# Button is cut only in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, bootstrap-4

In my web page I have a button. When I display the page in Chrome, everything works fine, but when I look at it in IE, the button text doesn't fit in the button (see image). Do you have a hint, what possibly causes this problem and how to fix it? I'm also using bootstrap v4.0.0.

[image: buttons: Chrome above, IE underneath]

Here is the code:

```css
.button {
  background-color: #002c4c;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-8 .col-lg-2 {
  max-width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-8">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <form action="/MyProject/print?language=de" method="post" name="printForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="_blank">

      <input type="submit" class="button" name="btn_print" value="PDF generieren">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I was not able to reproduce this error with the code snippet thing even when I put my whole web page & css inside it. I guess it has something to do with the bootstrap columns. I use lg-2 here with a max width of 225px.

[image: left chrome, right IE]

After I used the work-around (button instead of input) suggested in the answer I get the above. The button in IE is a bit smaller though it doesn't use up the max-width I defined. If anyone issues the same problem and has found a reason for that, I'd be glad to hear about it. For now, I'll live with the work-around.

Comment: do you use an webfont or is this a system font?

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim in body I define `font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: ok... so could you please try if this error occures when you do not use "Roboto" here (only to clarify if my idea is the right one)

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim yes, it still occurs. I've checked if I use Roboto somewhere else in the css but it's not the case.

Comment: You want to discuss a client-side problem, so show client-side code, please, and not stuff like `<fmt:message key="input.button.print" var="buttonPrint" />` Also, a proper testable live example (code snippet embedded here, or elsewhere) could help people reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CBroe I changed it to the HTML from client. I don't know how to use these code snipped things, I'm sorry. I assumed this would be a css problem.

Comment: If I run the snippet in my IE (11) it doesn't have any render bug

Comment: @SirExotic this seems not to reproduce the error, but thank you, I found where to enter the code snippet thing and I will now play along with it. Maybe I can reproduce the error and this might solve my problem then.

Comment: can you try if the problem is solved by using a button element instead?
      `<button type="submit" class="button" name="btn_print">PDF generieren</button>`

Comment: I was asking about the webfont because i already had the same error in IE11... it occured becaus the button was rendered before the webfont was loaded and was not redrawed when the webfont was renderd. If you inspect the button in IE11, and set it to `display: none` in the inspector and remove this again it is rendered correctly, am I right?

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim I tried this [inspecting the button with IE and changing the disüplay attribute], but it reappears wrong again.

Comment: I guess it will be quite hard to help here without beeing able to reproduce the error myselfe... I'm sorry... since I already had a similar error I will nevertheless post my answer to that here

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim changing it to button makes it appear in two lines `PDF <br> generieren`. This looks a bit strange but is okay for now ;D thank you. If you put it to an answer I'm going to accept it. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll already had the issue myselfe that a text overflows a button in IE11.

For me it was a rendering bug connected to fonts.

IE11 seems to render the button on pageload, before webfonts are loaded, when the webfont is loaded the button is not redrawed so it does not adapt to the new width.

The only solution I was able to find is forcing the browser to redraw when webfonts are loaded. Therfore I used an JS called "FontFaceObserver" (https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver)

JS:

```
new FontFaceObserver('Roboto', {
    style: 'normal',
    weight: 400,
}).load(function(){
    $('body').addClass('state-font-loaded');
}, 10000);
```

CSS:

```
.state-font-loaded {
    visibility: visible; //forcing browser to redraw
}
```

---

An other try would be to change the `input` into `button` like
`<button type="submit" class="button" name="btn_print">PDF generieren</button>` this could solve sizing issues if they are connected to the input element. (Please also inpect this element to see if there is any fixed or precentage width set)

Comment: could you add 'change input to button' please? (:

Comment: I added the `<button>` as additional way to test (thank for your vote, I'm glad I could somehow help, also it seems to be a workaround)